# Convert JavaScript number to two decimal places regardless of length

Tags: javascript

I am required to produce a NUMBER, not a string, in this format: XX.XX, regardless of whether there are any decimals. So, 600 --> 600.00, and 5.5678 --> 5.57. toFixed(2) will not achieve this result because it converts the number into a string, but it must be a number. parseFloat(num.toFixed(2)) does not acheive the correct result because while converting back to a number, parseFloat will strip any trailing zeros. 60 --> "60.00" --> 60. toPrecision will convert to a string, just like toFixed(), so this function will not work either.

Comment: What's the reason for needing only 2 decimal places? Is it possible you could represent it as an integer in code for calculations (i.e cents instead of dollars for currency) and divide by 100 when you want to represent it to the user with decimal places?

Comment: Javascript numbers are held as double precision floating point numbers in memory. They are not decimal numbers, are incapable of representing decimal digits after the decimal point exactly and don't have a format other than their binary representation. The use case behind the question might help

Answer (score 3):

There is no solution to this. You can't have insignificant trailing zeros in a JS number, just like you can't have insignificant leading zeros - there is simply no way for them to be represented in memory in the format they're stored in in essentially all JavaScript implementations ([IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)).

If you need to store your value as a number for procesing but keep track of the precision, you could store it as an object such as: 600.00 -> `{value: 600, decimals: 2}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only keep the numbers after the decimal place if they aren't zeros. It just isn't possible. In fact, my console will give me an error message if I have extra zeros. If you really need to do this, I suggest either doing it in Java, or doing something like this:

```
var number = 123456;
var stringNumber = number.toFixed(2);
var workableNumber = round(number*100)/100;
```

When displaying the number, use stringNumber. When using the number as a number, use workableNumber.

Comment: You suggest doing it in Java in a browser..?

Comment: He didn't say he needs it done in a browser. If he needs to do stuff like this often, then it might be a good idea to use a different programming language.

Comment: Fair enough. It's be a bit odd to switch programming languages just for that though. Is there a built-in class in Java that handles numbers with a precision tagged along?

Comment: Not that I know of, but it does let you have trailing zeros.

Comment: Not in the standard numeric types (`int`, `double` etc) it doesn't

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something differently then you are... my trailing zeros work just fine.

Comment: and of course you couldn't have trailing zeros in an int

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using the number XX.XX format for computing, you don't need the trailing zero. But if you need to display the '60.00'. You can convert it to string then search for '.' (dot) if exist. If '.' don't exist, just add '.00'.. If you can't understand my explanation, read my code.

```html
<script>
   var num1 = "60.75";
  var num2 = "60";
   alert(printDec(num1));
   alert(printDec(num2));
  function printDec(num){
    if(num.indexOf('.')<00){
      return num+".00";
     }
    else{
      return parseFloat(num)+"";
    }
  }
</script>
```